# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'. java.lang. Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.BuildConfig

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> 1 exception was raised by workers:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-Android-ScalableVideoView-10e7b4da8b-runtime.jar (com.github.adityaxjha:Android-ScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b) and jetified-android-scalablevideoview-1.0.1-runtime.jar (com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.PivotPoint found in modules jetified-Android-ScalableVideoView-10e7b4da8b-runtime.jar (com.github.adityaxjha:Android-ScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b) and jetified-android-scalablevideoview-1.0.1-runtime.jar (com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.ScalableType found in modules jetified-Android-ScalableVideoView-10e7b4da8b-runtime.jar (com.github.adityaxjha:Android-ScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b) and jetified-android-scalablevideoview-1.0.1-runtime.jar (com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.ScalableVideoView found in modules jetified-Android-ScalableVideoView-10e7b4da8b-runtime.jar (com.github.adityaxjha:Android-ScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b) and jetified-android-scalablevideoview-1.0.1-runtime.jar (com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.ScaleManager found in modules jetified-Android-ScalableVideoView-10e7b4da8b-runtime.jar (com.github.adityaxjha:Android-ScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b) and jetified-android-scalablevideoview-1.0.1-runtime.jar (com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.ScaleManager$1 found in modules jetified-Android-ScalableVideoView-10e7b4da8b-runtime.jar (com.github.adityaxjha:Android-ScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b) and jetified-android-scalablevideoview-1.0.1-runtime.jar (com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.Size found in modules jetified-Android-ScalableVideoView-10e7b4da8b-runtime.jar (com.github.adityaxjha:Android-ScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b) and jetified-android-scalablevideoview-1.0.1-runtime.jar (com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.1)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using **react-native-video**, Try to downgrade the **react-native-video** version instead.
"react-native-video": "**5.1.1**" is working for me

Comment: not working @THIEN VO

Comment: First remove the existing package(yarn remove react-native-video) and add again with specific version (yarn add react-native-video@5.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-native-video-processing
then you can try this solution
Inside node_module/ react-native-video/Android/app/build.gradel file.

replace that code

```
implementation 'com.github.adityaxjha:Android-ScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b'
```

with

```
implementation 'com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4'
```